# Getting table name from ComboBox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I have a problem with getting table name from my ComboBox to my query statement. I am populating my ComboBox with table names from MySQL by doing this:

```
glowneOkno.cbTabeleMySQL.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME"
glowneOkno.cbTabeleMySQL.DataSource = polaczenie.GetSchema("TABLES")
```

`cbTabeleMySQL` - this is my ComboBox, `polaczenie` - this is my connection to datebase

And this code above fills ComboBox correctly. But when I try to do a simple query by using this ComboBox:

```
Dim zapytanie As String = "SELECT * from " & cbTabeleMySQL.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

I get an error with DataRowView and I have no idea how to get a value text (table name) from this ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SelectedValue property of a combobox item actually gets the 'ValueMember' property of the combobox item which you aren't setting currently. Try adding

```
glowneOkno.cbTabeleMySQL.ValueMember= "TABLE_NAME"
```